# Firebase Cloud Messaging - iOS Badges

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want my Cloud Function to send a push notification to a specific topic, which works just fine. However, when I'm adding the "badge" field, the following error occurs:

```
Unknown name "badge" at 'message.notification': Cannot find field.
```

What am I supposed to do if I want to specify a badge number for iOS devices? The code I have looks like follows:

```
exports.onAddLog = functions.database.ref("/NodesLog/{id}").onCreate((change, context) => {
const payload = {
    "topic": "Channel123",
    "notification": {
      "title": "Test-Title",
      "body": "Test-Body",
      "badge": "1"
    },
    "data": {
        "test": "test",
        "notId": "123"
    }
}

const promise : Promise<any> = admin.messaging().send(payload)
.catch(error => console.error("Error on send: " + error))
.then(sendSuccess => console.log("Notification send "))
.catch(() => console.error("What happened?"))

return promise;
})
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is that badge is iOS field and it should be in another place as Ali said it is in "aps" object. But what he didn't say is where aps should be.

for example this should be your message

```
{
  "message":{
     "topic": "Channel123",
      "notification": {
          "title": "Test-Title",
          "body": "Test-Body",
          "badge": "1"
      },
     "data": {
         "test": "test",
         "notId": "123"
     },
     "apns": {
       "payload": {
         "aps": {
           "badge": 5
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

I took the example from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#data_messages)

Comment: So how come you now have two badge fields?

Comment: badge nested on notification will throw error. FirebaseMessagingError: Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "badge" at 'message.notification'

Answer (score 2):

try to add `aps` node containing `badge` property with your payload

```
const payload = {

    ...

    "aps":{  
      "alert":"test alert",
      "badge":5,
      "sound":"default"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following payload worked for me on both Android and iOS:

```
payload = {
      notification: {
        "title": "Message Title",
        "body": "Message Body",
        "click_action": ".MainActivity",
        "badge": "1",
      },
      data: {
        "my_message_type": "foo",
        "my_id": "bar",
      },
    };
```

Comment: This worked for me, while the others didn't.

Answer (score 1):

```
const payload = {
            token: "FCMToken",
            notification: {
              title: "title",
              body: "body",
            },
            apns: {
              payload: {
                aps: {
                  badge: 5,
                  sound: "default",
                },
              },
            },
          };
```

Comment: thanks this is the only one that working on cloud function send to iOS